# Core data model, game has a winner and a loser, a player has multiple games?

Tags: ios, core-data, xcdatamodel

I'm trying to setup my core data model.  I want to have a game that has one loser and one winner.  And I need a Player that has multiple games.

I have the following:

Entity: 
Player

Attributes:
wins,
losses,
name

Relationships:
games Destination:Game inverse: ??? winner or loser???

Entity:
Game

Attributes:
losingScore,
winningScore,

Relationships:
loser destination:Player Inverse:games,
winner destination:Player Inverse:games

How can I set this up??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just:

- player.gamesWon<->game.winner  (game:to-one)
- player.gamesLost<->game.loser (game:to-one)
- player.games<->game.players (game:to-many)

You could incidentally then have wins/losses as gamesWon.count and gamesLost.count and not as attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this...

A game has players. Each player in the game achieves a score. Whether they win or lose depends on their score compared to the other player's score for that game.

My suggestion...

---

- Entity: `Player`
- Attribute: `NSString *name`
- Relationship: `playerGames` one-to-many `Game`

---

- Entity: `Game`
- Attribute: `NSString *reference` (e.g. Game "1")
- Attribute: `NSNumber *scorePlayer1`
- Attribute: `NSNumber *scorePlayer2`
- (Attribute: `NSDate *timeStamp`) option?
- Relationship: `gamePlayer1` many-to-one `Player`
- Relationship: `gamePlayer2` many-to-one `Player` (where player 2 cannot equal player 1)

---

So then we can have...

```
Game *game = [[Game alloc] init...];

if (game.scorePlayer1 > game.scorePlayer2) {
    NSLog("%@ is winner and %@ is loser with score %@-%@", game.gamePlayer1.name, gamePlayer2.name, scorePlayer1, scorePlayer2);
} else if (game.scorePlayer2 > game.scorePlayer1) {
    NSLog("%@ is winner and %@ is loser with score %@-%@", game.gamePlayer2.name, gamePlayer1.name, scorePlayer2, scorePlayer1);
} else {
    NSLog("Players %@ and %@ drew with score %@-%@", game.gamePlayer1.name, gamePlayer2.name, scorePlayer1, scorePlayer2);
}

Player *player = [[Player alloc] init...];

NSFetchRequest *requestWins = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntity:@"Game"];
NSPredicate *predicateAsPlayer1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"(%@ >= %@) && (game.gamePlayer1.name == %@)", game.scorePlayer1, game.scorePlayer2, player];
NSPredicate *predicateAsPlayer2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"(%@ >= %@) && (game.gamePlayer2.name == %@)", game.scorePlayer2, game.scorePlayer1, player];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[predicateAsPlayer1, predicateAsPlayer2]];
[requestWins setPredicate:predicate];
NSArray *arrayWins = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:requestWins];

NSFetchRequest *requestLosses = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntity:@"Game"];
...<repeat similar to above>...
NSArray *arrayLosses = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:requestLosses];

NSInteger gamesPlayed = player.playerGames.count;
NSInteger gamesWon = arrayWins.count;
NSInteger gamesLost = arrayLosses.count;
NSInteger gamesDrawn = gamesPlayed - gamesWon - gamesLost;
```

Hope this helps.